# In what way is the existential and universal quantifiers treated differently by the rules of $\forall$-introduction and $\exists$-introduction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

In Natural Deduction in what way is the existential and universal quantifiers treated differently by the rules of $\forall$-introduction and $\exists$-introduction?

They look really similar in their definitions?:

$\forall$-introduction: $\frac{\frac{}{A(c)}}{\forall x A(x)}$ Provided that **c** is a new constant symbol

$\exists$-introduction: $\frac{A(t)}{\exists x A(x)}$

Comment: I think the major difference is, in $\forall$-introduction, you need to provide a subproof of $A(c)$ where $c$ is an introduced atomic symbol.  Whereas in $\exists$-introduction, $t$ can be any term in the language, including a complex term, for which the substitution $A(x)[x := t]$ can be proved.

Comment: $\exists$-intro: if we have proved (or assumed) that $A(t)$ holds, i.e. that some "object" named $t$ has "property" $A$, we can safely deduce that "there is something that is $A$". Please, note: proved or assumed: if we have assumed $A(t)$, obviously the conclusion: $\exists x \ A(x)$ holds under the same assumption.

Comment: $\forall$-intro: we can use also a variable $y$ in place of $c$, but the proviso still holds: it must be "new". This mean that there are no assumptions about $c$ or $y$ in the context of the proof. This fact formalize the intuitive understanding that $c$ or $y$ being "new" means that they are "generic". If so, we have that, if $A$ holds for a "generic object", then it holds for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, say $c$ is  a constant symbol. Then the rule tells you that you can conclude $\exists{x}A(x)$, but you certainly can't conclude $\forall{x}A(x)$.

For an example: Suppose you are working with real numbers and $A(0)$ is stating that $\forall{y}$ $0.y=0$ (i.e. multiply any number by $0$ and you get back $0$). So it is correct to conclude $\exists{x}\forall{y}$ $x.y=x$ (i.e. there is some number s.t. if you multiply any number with that number you get the initial number back). It is certainly not correct to conclude $\forall{x}\forall{y}$ $x.y=x$ (i.e. the product of any two numbers is equal to the first number.)

Edit 1: I'm not really clear on what you mean by "new", but I think the point that is being attempted is the following (suppose that the only constant symbols you have are $0,1$): Suppose that you assume $c$ is some arbitrary element and you manage to prove some thing about $c$, then you can conclude for all $x$. For example, suppose $c$ is non-zero number. Then you can prove $\exists{y}$ s.t. $c.y=1$. So you can conclude for all $x$, if $x$ is non-zero, then there is some $y$ s.t. $x.y=1$. However you have $1.1=1$. You can't conclude for all $x$, $x.x=x$. But you can conclude there is some $x$ for which $x.x=x$

Comment: Sorry I updated my definition ( it was wrong )

Comment: If you parameterize the entailment judgement with a signature that specifies the constants (and their arities if necessary), then having a "new" or "fresh" constant can be simply described as extending the signature. I briefly describe this in the "The Signature" section of [this article](http://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/understanding-typing-judgments.html). With this perspective the rules for universal/existential introduction look like: $$\frac{\Gamma\vdash_{\Sigma,c}P(c)}{\Gamma\vdash_\Sigma\forall x.P(x)}\qquad\frac{\Gamma\vdash_\Sigma P(t)}{\Gamma\vdash_\Sigma\exists x.P(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

The $\exists Intro$ has no restrictions, because as soon as something ($t$) has property $A$, then of course there is something that has property $A$. So, from $A(t)$ you can infer $\exists x A(x)$, no matter what $t$ is, or how $t$ came about.

The $\forall Intro$ works quite differently. You want to show that $\forall x A(x)$.  How can you show that?  Because $A(t)$ for some $t$? Clearly that is not enough ... You need to know that $A(t)$ is true for *all* $t$'s!  OK, so how do we show that? Well, if we assume that $c$ is some completely arbitrary object from our domain (and we do this by *introducing* a *new* symbol $c$, so we can ensure that we don't know anything about $c$ other than that it is some object from our domain), and we can show that $c$ has property $A$, then we can conclude that all objects have property $A$.

In short, if *any* object $c$ has property $A$ (i.e. If $A(c)$ for a *newly introduced* $c$), then *all* objects have property $A$ (I.e. then  $\forall x A(x)$)